# System error 123. SNMP set

Tags: delphi, snmp, system-error

I don't get it, same code work fine with Comtech modem.

oidOut: const string array
vout: string array

```
procedure TDamocles1208.SNMPset;
var
    mySNMP: TidSNMP;
    I: integer;
begin
      mySNMP:=TidSNMP.Create(nil);
      mySNMP.Query.Host:=Trim(IpEdt.Text);
      mySNMP.Query.Community:=Trim(ComStrEdt.Text);
      mySNMP.ReceiveTimeout:=1000;
    try
      mySNMP.Query.Clear;
      mySNMP.Query.PDUType:= PDUSetRequest;
        for I := 1 to 8 do
        begin
          mySNMP.Query.MIBAdd(oidOut[I],vOut[I],ASN1_INT);
            if mySNMP.SendQuery   then
            ShowMessage('Updated!')
            else
            ShowMessage('Update Failed!');
        end;
    finally
        mySNMP.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Error message here:

First chance exception at $7588D3CF. Exception class EOSError with message
'System Error. Code:123
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax incorrect'.
Process Project1.exe (1060)

Comment: That is a very odd error for a socket-based operation.  What does the call stack look like when the exception is raised?

Comment: SNMPget shows not connected but still get the exact D.O value.

I think in the loops, sometimes it works, sometimes no.

[link](http://i.imgur.com/iqHX8PW.png)

[link](http://i.imgur.com/bCgKKhb.png)]


SNMP set:

- Without SendQuery check, it doesn't so error but can't set value.

[link](http://i.imgur.com/ogCLEIm.png)

- Add SendQuery check, that error again

[link](http://i.imgur.com/Na08J3v.png)

Comment: SNMP is UDP-based. `Connected` is only true if you call `Connect()` to bind the socket to a remote IP/Port. `SendQuery()` does not require `Connect()`, and you should not be relying on `Connected` being true before calling `SendQuery()`. With that said, you did not answer my question. What does the debugger show for the call stack when the exception is raised?

Comment: kernelbase raiseexception+0x54
[link](http://i.imgur.com/n4RRNXC.png)
[link](http://i.imgur.com/kO2E9s3.png)

Comment: Both screenshots show that `TIdStackWindows.HostByName()` is failing, which means the `Query.Host` you have assigned cannot be resolved to an IP address.  Double-check your input. And try doing a command-line ping to verify that your PC's DNS subsystem is working correctly.

Comment: Problem solved...

"mySNMP.Query.Clear;" is my fault...

In previous program, I use  "mySNMP.Host" and "mySNMP.Community"
so clear query didn't affect.

This time, it's "mySNMP.Query.Host". So it clear the IP and community string before send query.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: By the way,  could you please explain the difference between SNMP.Query.Host and SNMP.Host?

Comment: `SNMP.Host` is the main property you should use. `Query.Clear` copies `SNMP.Host` to `Query.Host` so it has a local copy when encoding its data. `Query`, `Reply` and `Trap` are all based on the same class, which has its own `Host` so it does not modify the main `SNMP.Host`£when receiving replies and traps.